# Error when install ZK Studio on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, zk, kepler

I've install eclipse kepler Java Developer EE and install ZK Studio throung Market place. But Errors Appear :

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was
>
> > :(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org. eclipse. equinox. internal. p2.
> >     engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). Unable to read repository
> >     at studio. zkoss
> >     .org/resource/plugins/eclipse42/plugins/org.zkoss.eclipse.editor2.0.1.v201312091448.jar.
> >     Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected:
> >     5833581; received: 5816781 Unable to read repository at
> >     http://studio.zkoss.org/resource/plugins/eclipse42/plugins/org.zkoss.eclipse.pack2.0.1.v201312091448.jar.
> >     Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected:
> >     7912681; received: 7874881 Unable to read repository at
> >     http://studio.zkoss.org/resource/plugins/eclipse42/plugins/org.zkoss.eclipse.setting2.0.1.v201312091448.jar.
> >     Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected:
> >     779524; received: 778124 Unable to read repository at
> >     http://studio.zkoss.org/resource/plugins/eclipse42/plugins/org.zkoss.eclipse.zks2.0.1.v201312091448.jar.
> >     Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected:
> >     2501827; received: 2496227

What should I do to solve this problem and continue install ZK Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. I check my firewall it turn out the firewall is enabled. so I disabled the firewall and continue install zk.

Thanks,

Dian